# Theme Action to hook for one time only function

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am developing a custom theme. After my theme is activated/installed I need to run a one time only function that will set some options. What is the best action to hook for this?

Should I use `after_setup_theme`? My understanding is that this event/action fires on each page load so I don't think I should use this action correct?

*Ps: is it best to place this code in my functions.php file or somewhere else? (I am using the underscores theme template).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "theme activation". Using the customizer you can change settings for any theme on the server, whether it is "active" or not, but at that context the theme will be active and if your code will not work correctly in that context users might be upset.

If you need to build a DB for your theme, just store a version indication, and use one of the available hooks to perform DB upgrade when there is a version mismatch between what the current version expect to find, and what is actually there. But be careful, judging from your other question, you want to create front end posts, and that should be done only when the user specifically initiates the action.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try this not so clean approach :)

```
    add_action('after_setup_theme','oneTimeStuffUponThemeSwitch');

    function oneTimeStuffUponThemeSwitch()
    {
        if (is_admin())
        {
            global $pagenow;

            if(isset($_GET['activated']) && $pagenow == "themes.php")
            {
                //your custom code
            }
        }
    }
```

Yes, you are right, this action fires at each page load, however the function checks if you are activating your theme, so that you execute your custom only once.
Yes, you can paste it in your functions.php file.